# No reconoce imágenes debido a error NullPointerException

Tags: java, jar

Tengo una aplicación en `Java` con la cual he generado el .`jar` pero no me coge las `imágenes` iniciales de la aplicación debido a un error de NullPointerException.

Tengo las `imágenes` guardadas en una `carpeta`, al mismo nivel que las demás.

Os adjunto capturas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Por qué tengo este problema con la excepción y no me corre el programa?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que para acceder a una imagen que se encuentra empaquetada dentro del JAR debes hacerlo como lo que es un recurso en el CLASSPATH y no como un archivo en el sistema de archivos.

El constructor de la clase`ImageIcon` que recive un `String` no te sirve en este caso porque espera un nombre de archivo el cual buscará en el sistema de archivos.

Por lo tanto debes hacer uso del método [Class.getResource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) de la siguiente manera:

```
URL imageUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/insertar.png");
ImageIcon ico_insertar = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
```

**NOTA:** Desde el IDE te funciona sin problemas puesto que este ejecuta la aplicación usando los archivos `.class` que están en el sistema de archivos por lo que puede encontrar las imágenes sin problema.

Comment: Me salta un error de excepción. run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
 at interfaz.Index.<init>(Index.java:18)
 at interfaz.Index$9.run(Index.java:240)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)

Comment: He añadido el siguiente código:
 URL url_insertar = this.getClass().getResource("./src/imagenes/modificar.png");
 ImageIcon ico_insertar = new ImageIcon(url_insertar);
        
        button_insertar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_insertar.getImage().getScaledInstance(button_insertar.getWidth()-10, button_insertar.getHeight()-10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
       
pero me da ese error de excepción.

Comment: Porque no lo has hecho como te dije. Elimina esta parte: "./src". Debe quedarte exactamente como puse en la respuesta.