# **Cuando ejecuto el fichero .jar no se porque no lee el fichero .dat**

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Muy buenas soy nuevo en programación en java, he intentado hacer un jar en netbeans y al hacerlo se crea normalmente pero cuando lo ejecuto no me deja acceder a **los datos de mi fichero .dat el sistema me dice que está vacío**. Al inicio lo guardo en el fichero .dat. Aquí les dejo un poco del código como guardo. el proyecto está hecho javafx.

```
 public void escribirObjeto(String server, String user, String pass) {
        ConfigDB config;

        try {
            try (ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(creacionVerificacionFichero(rutaDB), true))) {
                config = new ConfigDB(server, user, pass);
                objOut.writeObject(config);
                objOut.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Fichero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Fichero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

y aquí es como recupero los datos del fichero y lo guardo en el objeto.

```
public ConfigDB leerObjetoDB() {
        ConfigDB config = new ConfigDB();
        try {
            try (ObjectInputStream objetInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(rutaDB))) {
                config = (ConfigDB) objetInput.readObject();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException | EOFException ex) {
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Fichero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return config;
    }
```

Aquí es donde le asigno los valores para conectarme la Data base.

```
private void extraerDatos() {
        File file = new File("src/configuracionadministrador/configDB.dat");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Fichero datosDB = new Fichero();
            setServer(datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getServer());
            setUser(datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getUsuario());
            setPass(datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getPass());
            System.out.println(datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getServer()+" -> "+datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getUsuario()+" -> "+datosDB.leerObjetoDB().getPass());
            
        }
        
    }
public Connection conectar() {
        try {
            if (extraerDatos()) {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(getServer(), getUser(), getPass());
            } else {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(getServer(), getUser(), getPass());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConexionDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) { 
            Alertas.errorSQL("Conexion", ex);
            Alertas.mensajeInformación("Conexión", "Usuario, Contraseña o\nBase de Datos incorrectas");
        }
        return conexion;
    }
```

Comment: Esto soluciona tu problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347943/no-reconoce-im%c3%a1genes-debido-a-error-nullpointerexception/348064#348064

Comment: En el IDE si me deja ingresar, pero cuando ejecuto el .jar no me deja leer y  he visto sobre la ruta, no me deja poner un .getClass().getResourse() no lo reconoce la ruta File

Comment: La ruta que debes usar es `configuracionadministrador/configDB.dat`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta solo tenia que poner ./configDB.dat nada más.